# Integrating osmosis and python to get data from .osm files

Tags: python, subprocess, openstreetmap, osmosis

I'm trying to filter data from .osm file, using a python script

Following is the python code I used for the purpose. But the .osm file created does not contain the data from the input file.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['C:/Users/91957/Desktop/osmosis/bin/osmosis.bat','--read-xml','C:/Users/91957/Desktop/osm_test/Sample_input.osm',
                 '--nkv','keyValueList="amenity.fast_food"','--write-xml','C:/Users/91957/Desktop/osm_test/fast_food.osm'])
```

But when running following command on command line it works like charm.

```
osmosis --read-xml file=Sample_input.osm --nkv keyValueList="amenity.fast_food" --write-xml file=fast_food.osm
```

Comment: You are not passing the same arguments. In your python script it is `C:/Users/91957/Desktop/osm_test/Sample_input.osm` while on the command line it is `file=Sample_input.osm`. Maybe that's the reason but I've never worked with osmosis so far. Btw. maybe you want to switch from osmosis to [osmium-tool](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) which is faster and sometimes less weird :)

Comment: On command line my path is already set to the directory which contains the Sample_input.osm file.

Comment: Scai mentions osmium-tool above.  That uses the "osmium" library, and there are some python bindings for that - see https://github.com/osmcode/pyosmium .  Never tried it, but I'd start there if I were you.